# How do I display an image from an input:file element I before the form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using the express-fileupload module. I have also written some jquery to try and make this work. What I see most of the time is the case where the image is sent to the database gotten back for display. But, in my case, once I attach the image to the input element, I want the image to be displayed through an `img` tag, before final form submission. I look forward to hearing from anyone. Thank you.

**//app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

//Connect to db
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected to mongoDB');
});

//Init app
var app = express();

//View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//Set public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Set global errors variable
app.locals.errors = null;

// Express FileUpload middleware
app.use(fileUpload());

//Body Parser Middleware
//
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//express session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    // cookie: { secure: true }
  }));

//express-validator middleware
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;

        while(namespace.length) {
            formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
        }
        return {
            param : formParam,
            msg : msg,
            value: value
        };
    }
}));

//Express messages middleware
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

//set routes
var pages = require('./routes/pages');
var adminPages = require('./routes/admin_pages');
var adminCategories = require('./routes/admin_categories');
var adminProducts = require('./routes/admin_products');

app.use('/admin', pages);
app.use('/admin/pages', adminPages);
app.use('/admin/categories', adminCategories);
app.use('/admin/Products', adminProducts); 

var port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

**//add_products.js**

```
 router.get('/add-product', function (req, res) {
        var title = "";
        var desc = "";
        var price = "";

        Category.find(function(err, categories) {
            res.render('admin/add_product', {
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                categories: categories,
                price: price
            });
        });
    });
```

**//add_product.ejs**

```
<%- include('../_layouts/adminheader') %>

<h2 class="page-title">Add a product</h2>
<a href="/admin/products" class="btn btn-primary">Back to all products</a>
<br><br>

<form method="post" action="/admin/products/add-product" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<%= title %>" placeholder="Title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="desc" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Description"><%= desc %></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Category</label>
        <select name="category" class="form-control">
            <% categories.forEach(function(cat) { %>
            <option value="<%= cat.slug %>">
                <%= cat.title %>
            </option>
            <% }); %>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" value="<%= price %>" placeholder="Price">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="img">
        <img src="#" id="imgPreview" alt="" />
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $("#imgPreview").attr('src', e.target.result).width(100).height(100);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#img").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });

</script>

<%- include('../_layouts/adminfooter') %>
```

Comment: do you see the image file uploaded in the backend . Does your static path includes path of the backend where image file is present .

Comment: @TanmayPatil, I only specified the public folder as a static path. The folder where I intend to save the image is in an image folder which is inside the public folder.